# How can two arguments be passed to a method with a one-argument signature?

Tags: ruby, proc-object, arity

```
s = Proc.new {|x|x*2}

def one_arg(x)
  puts yield(x)
end

one_arg(5, &s)
```

How does `one_arg` know about `&s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` operator turns the Proc into a block, so it becomes a one-argument method with a block (which is called with `yield`). If you had left off the `&` so that it passed the Proc directly, you would have gotten an error.

Answer (score 3):

By doing the `&s`, you're telling `one_arg` that you'd like your Proc `s` passed as a block (please correct me if I'm wrong). An equivalent writing would be

```
one_arg(5) do |x|
  x *2
end
```

There have been a few questions here on SO as of late that deal with this. [August Lilleaas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26051/august-lilleaas) has a pretty nice [write up](http://august.lilleaas.net/procs%5Fand%5Fblocks%5Fand%5Fanonymous%5Ffunctions) about some of the intricacies of all this Ruby madness.